# asp.net C# DB Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection

i am trying to learn ASP.NET but i am stuck when it comes to DB connections how can i create db connection class for oledbDataReader. 
please help me guys im new in asp.net C# can you correct my code?

```
public class AccessDb
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    private OleDbCommand m_cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    public  OleDbCommand Command 
    {
        get { return m_cmd; }
    }

    public AccessDb()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public IDataReader ExecReader(string sql)
    {
      try
      {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        this.m_cmd.CommandText = sql;

        if (this.m_cmd.Connection == null)
        {
            this.m_cmd.Connection = con;
        }

        this.m_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        return this.m_cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Start off by telling us what you are expecting from the code and where it is going wrong. Asking Can you correct my code, is not going to get you any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your return code as below and don't close the connection in your final block.

```
return this.m_cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection):
```